# Sending push notifications with APNS-Sharp

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I use APNS-Sharp in my server and it works perfect, except in one scenario, I'll try to describe it:

1. Server sends first push - NotificationService successfully connecting
      to apple servers, i get the "Connecting" and "Connected" events,
      QueueNotification method returns true, i get the "NotificationSuccess"
      event and the target device gets the push.
2. Server sending more push notifications - working great the
   QueueNotification method returns true, i get the "NotificationSuccess" event and the target devices get the push.
3. Server not sending push for few hours (2-3 hours)
4. Server send push - HERE IS MY PROBLEM, after sending this push the
   QueueNotification method returns TRUE i even get the
   "NotificationSuccess" event BUT the target device DON'T get the push.
5. Server send another push- the QueueNotification method returns true
   but this time i get the error event "Error: Unable to write data
   to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly
   closed by the remote host." then NotificationService reconnecting to
   apple servers and we back in step 1. (also the push successfully sent
   and the target device gets it)

So to sum it up, if my server start sending push notifications and then stop for 2-3 hours, the next push he send after the break doesn't arrive to the target device even though I get the "NotificationSuccess" event and i don't get any error event till i send another push.